# ASP.NET Wizard step scroll position

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, scroll, postback, wizard

I have an ASP.NET form with multiple steps (using the Wizard control). When advancing to the next step, I want the page to start at the top, but for some reason it is maintaining the scroll position. I set the Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback property to false, and I have the next button event handler set it to false also. I don't have the property set to true anywhere. But it is still maintaining the scroll position. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I just discovered that I had my Wizard and navigation buttons inside of an update panel. That was what was keeping the scroll position in place.